# any way to get rotation cube on xmonad/i3

Tags: xmonad, compiz, tiling-wm, animation

I really like xmonad and I used to it on my arch station. But recently I remembered *no clue why out of fashion* rotating cube animation effect, that was available with compiz (or kwin, but I don't like it so much). So my question - is it possible to somehow enable this animation for workspace switching in xmonad (or at least at any other tiling wm like i3 or awesome)? Its not necessary has to be compiz. I can make compiz enabled under xfce, or xmonad --replace in xfce to enable xmonad under xfce, but not both.

thanks.

Comment: Considering how compiz is a window manager and xmonad is a window manager, I'd guess that you can only have one or the other. There isn't a tiling wm that I know of that has compiz-like effects.

Comment: yes, I get it, but isn't there some standalone composite manager, not composite window manager, to make such animation? I looked in compton and xcompmgr, and haven't find workspace switching animations..

Comment: I suppose that's because a virtual workspace is window manager concept. Standalone compositor won't have any idea of what the WM is doing - it just composites the windows.